# Can not figure out where these google web fonts are coming from

Tags: fonts, request, webfonts, google-fonts, roboto

I'm trying to optimize my website with different kind of tools such as Yellow Lab Tools and GTmetrix, and when I was checking what web fonts are loaded in the top page, I found these two web fonts links that I do not recognize.

https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.woff (19.4 KB)
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.woff (19.5 KB)

I have no idea what these are for and where they are used.
Is there any way to stop loading these two web fonts?

I've checked my css files and js files and everything, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Here is the top page of my website.

http://run-journey.com/

There are the only fonts I use in my website.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Noto Sans JP";
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:400;
  font-display:swap;
  src: 
    url('/fonts/NotoSans_Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('/fonts/NotoSans_regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/NotoSans_regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Noto Sans JP";
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:700;
  font-display:swap;
  src: 
    url('/fonts/NotoSans_Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('/fonts/NotoSans_bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/NotoSans_bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}


@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:400;
  font-display:swap;
  src: 
    url('/fonts/lato-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('/fonts/lato-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/lato-v15-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:700;
  font-display:swap;
  src: 
    url('/fonts/lato-v15-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('/fonts/lato-v15-latin-700.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/lato-v15-latin-700.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Any advise would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I checked. 
Your font's are Lato! there are no problem with your fonts. I can't find those two links in your website.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Noto Sans JP for japanese texts and Lato for English. That's why I don't know how I get those two links for "roboto" font.

Comment: but I can't see those links. I mean that there are no problem with your fonts. remove your browser cache.

Comment: Would you run a test and check if you could see those links here?
https://yellowlab.tools/
Run the test and check the part “Webfonts number”. It says 7, which includes those two links, 4 links of my fonts, and icon link that I’m using.